# Set date field on form to current date, but when accessed later the date stays the same

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, date

I am making an online form to fill out for a workflow. However the website through schoolmessenger is hard set that once the form is submitted it still stays in code format. My issue is that for my Date submitted field I want it to where they cant change it. So I edited the code to automatically pull today's date and it can't be changed. However each time they go back for revisions the date updates to the current date. I need a way to fix this problem and I don't want them to be able to change the date because it prevents the user from setting dates in the past to try to beat the system. Here is a sample of my current code.

```
<div class="form-row"><label for="dateSubmitted">DATE FORM SUBMITTED:</label><input class="dateSubmitted" disabled="disabled" form_message="Please+select+Today%27s+Date" id="dateSubmitted" name="dateSubmitted" type="text" /><script>
$('.dateSubmitted').datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
var date2 = $('.dateSubmitted').datepicker('getDate');
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+5); 

</script></div>
```

Above is what I have for date submitted. Next is two fields that rely on the date submitted.

```
<div class="form-row"><label for="dateLeaving">DATE LEAVING:</label><input class="dateLeaving" form_mandatory="true" form_message="Please+enter+the+date+you+are+planning+to+leave." id="dateLeaving" name="dateLeaving" type="text" /><script>
$('.dateLeaving').datepicker({
    minDate: date2
   });
```

```
<div class="form-row"><label for="dateReturning">DATE RETURNING:</label><input class="dateReturning" form_mandatory="true" form_message="Please+select+the+date+you+are+planning+to+return." id="dateReturning" name="dateReturning" type="text" /><script>
$('.dateReturning').datepicker({
    minDate: date2
   });
```

Comment: `"I don't want them to be able to change the date"` - Then it has to be done server-side.  The user can change any values they want in their browser.  As for the date updating... It's currently being set in JavaScript code, so it's going to be set any time the page loads.  If you want to store a value for later use on another load of the page, it has to be stored somewhere.  Server-side is ideal, though you could also store it in client-side locations like local storage or a cookie (all user-editable, of course).

Comment: Hmm well the website we use is for a school run through a company called school messenger, not sure how we would do a server side option. I basically just want them to only change date returning and date arriving in retrospect to date submitted, I just wish there was a way to hard set date submitted to the first time the form was used and the other two date pickers rely on that hard set date.  You say that server side storage is the only way? Wouldn't that end up holding an exceeding amount of variables?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "an exceeding amount of variables".  But in terms of input restrictions, any actual forced restriction would have to be done server-side.  Users can submit any values they want to the server.  You can write client-side code to fill in values for the user, but they can change those values if they want.

Comment: When I said "exceeding amount of variables" I guess I misunderstood, to me I read that as the form would store the variable on the server, but if we had multiple users creating a form to me that seemed as if that would create mass variables or constantly override the variable with what other users were selecting. But I get what you mean, the form calls an external code that stores the variables and just updates them in the form. However that doesn't fix the issue if they can change it and it would still change the input the next time the form is opened...unless you have an example.

Comment: The user can't change anything that's happening on the server unless you allow them to.  What we're talking about is server-side validation.  The user can submit any values they want to the server, and you can't stop them.  But you would write logic in your server-side code which validates that what the user sends you is authorized.  If it isn't, you can simply return an error to the user and not process their request.  In client-side code you can run the same validation, but you can't *guarantee* it.  Because you can't actually control the client.

Comment: Do you know or have an example of the type of codes on both sides that would do this validation? It has been years since I did any java and it would help with some sort of visual.

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to validate.  There is no general "input validation" code.  For example, in the question above it sounds like there's some rule or set of rules you have to determine if a date is "valid".  Whatever those rules are, you'd write code to enforce them.